# Calculating XY from Depth, Azimuth, Inclination using Python

Tags: python, coordinate-system

I have been using the answer from here and trying to see what I am doing wrong, but just don't see anything.

```
dMD = D2 - D1
B = acos(cos(I2 - I1) - (sin(I1)*sin(I2)*(1-cos(A2-A1))))
RF = 2 / B * tan(B / 2)
dX = dMD/2 * (sin(I1)*sin(A1) + sin(I2)*sin(A2))*RF
dY = dMD/2 * (sin(I1)*cos(A1) + sin(I2)*cos(A2))*RF

X2 = X1 + dX
Y2 = Y1 + dX
```

[image]

The blue are the correct points, but the red is what i end up with.

I've tried to convert to radians as well, with similar results, offset from actual location. I've also tried several different projections

Is there something that i'm missing?

Edit.
So the mistake relating to dX and dY, which would explain the offset and although my inclination appeared to be in radians, it seems it wasn't.

Comment: you seem to be using spherical geometry in a planar coordinate system

Comment: Correct, maybe i'm missing something but i tried using ESPG:3857, which is a spherical crs, correct? with the same results

Comment: EPSG:3657 is also planar, try EPSG:4326 or stay on a plane and use pythagorous

Comment: It looks to me like your azimuth is in degrees but your inclination is in radians, yet your algorithm treats them as if they have the same units.  Is Depth the length of pipe down the hole, or true vertical depth?

Comment: it's length of the pipe, but i have both available Measured and True Vertical. I did also try converting azimuth to radians

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: Use of these formulae requires both azimuth and inclination to be in radians. For the azimuths, simply multiply all of them by pi/180. However, you will need to clarify how your inclination is expressed.- is it already in radians r or is it some measure of downward slope?. In the mineral world, drill "dip" would be expressed as a declination (negative inclination)- e.g. -80 for a hole dipping at 80 degrees below horizontal. Then the value required for use in the fomulae would be the difference between this and vertical, expressed as radians.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the last line in your formula list should be Y2 = Y1 + dY (not dX as you have written it). Once you have converted each of the azimuths to radians (*Pi()/180) and assuming the inclinations are as radians already then I think you will be ok. However, your code should check the condition that B= 0 because if it is then the "RF" calculation will cause a divide by zero error.